# Add border to all images

Tags: graphics

I have a document that has a handful of figures in it, and I am using

```
\tcbox{\includegraphics{./Pictures/image-name.png}}
```

to put a border around them. I end up repeating this for every image though. Is there a way to put something at the top of my document that says to apply this to all images? I was thinking it could work if I make a custom environment but I couldn't find examples of how to do that with images.

Comment: `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` adds additional options for `\includegraphics` such as `[fbox=0pt 0.333em]` (same border as tikz).  Not sure if it works with `\setkeys{Gin}`

Comment: Alas, tried `\setkeys{Gin}{fbox=0pt 0.333em}` with no joy.

Comment: `\newcommand\foo[1]{\tcbox{\includegraphics{./Pictures/#1.png}}}` .... `\foo{image-name}` .... `\foo{image-name2}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Feel free to open an answer because I believe you are right. That way I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I would recommend `\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\tcbox{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}`, which allows you to use `\includegraphics` in the traditional way (so the code makes sense), yet every `\includegraphics` is internally wrapped within a `\tcbox`.

Comment: @Werner not `\let` on a command with optionl arguments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In this instance it didn't matter, but true. `\NewCommandCopy` would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own abbreviation, eg

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{\tcbox{\includegraphics{./Pictures/#1.png}}}

 .... 
\foo{image-name}
 .... 
\foo{image-name2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Diabolical, but it works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{trim=-10pt -10pt -10pt -10pt}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit? I haven't used Gin before so I'm not exactly sure how this is working.

Comment: See page 14 of the graphicx manual (4.6 Setting Global Keys).  The trim key is usually used to trim off the edges of a picture.  Evidently, negative values add a border.

Comment: @JohnKormylo no code in the package actively makes it add a border, I think the effect will depend on which tex engine you are using  and which PDF viewer you use. interesting effect though, what made you think to try this?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - After the failure of [fbox=0pt] I was wondering which keywords work (with Gin) and which do not.  I was looking through the manual and saw trim...

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3973372#3973372

Comment: If you do not specify the width and/or height, negative trim increases the width and height (as measured by \sbox).  If you specify the width or height, it scales the image to keep the specified dimension (including the border).